# SQL Select First Name and Doesn't Contain Last Name Matching

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with FirstName and LastName.

```
FirstName   LastName
John        Smith
John        Taylor
Steve       White
Adam        Scott
Jane        Smith
Jane        Brown
```

I want to select LastName that does not contain "Smith". If it matchs, don't use any of the same FirstName

Output Result

```
FirstName   LastName
Steve       White
Adam        Scott
```

Notice "John Taylor" and "Jane Brown" aren't in the result, because the other John and Jane name contain Smith.

My current query (includes John Taylor and Jane Brown):

```
Select FirstName, LastName
From tablPerson
where LastName != "Smith"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from tablPerson p
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablPerson p2
                  where p2.LastName = 'Smith' and p2.FirstName = p.FirstName
                 );
```

I prefer `not exists` for this type of query because it has more intuitive behavior if any first names are `NULL`.  If any of the first names for `'Smith'` are `NULL`, then `not in` returns the empty set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub query to filter out all the persons whose last name contains Smith, as mentioned below:

```
select first_name, last_name from person 
where first_name not in ( 
select first_name from person where last_name like '%Smith%');
```

Here's the example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b250/2/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Name
where firstName not in 
(Select firstName from Name where lastName like '%Smith%')
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for good measure... with those strains from Dvořák's New World Symphony playing in the background

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.firstname = x.firstname 
   AND y.lastname = 'smith' 
 WHERE y.firstname IS NULL;
```